# Looking to find specific phrases in file using Python

Tags: python, regex

I am aware that there are some quite similar posts about this on the forum but I need this for a quick scan of a text file. I have to run 500 checks through a 1 GB file and print out lines that contain certain phrases, here is my code:

```
import re
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    searchstrings = ('aaAa','bBbb')
    for line in f.readlines():
        for word in searchstrings:
            word2 = ".*" + word + ".*"
            match = re.search(word2, line)
            if match:
                print word + "     " + line
```

I was trying to make it return any line containing those phrases, so even if the line was "BBjahdAAAAmm" I wanted it returned because it has aaaa in it. aaAa and bBbb are just examples, the list is completely different.

Comment: Why not `if word2.lower() in line.lower():` instead of using regex?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `f.readlines()`  You'll be loading the whole 1GB into memory. Read them one at a time.

Instead do:

```
searchstrings = ('aaAa','bBbb')
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in searchstrings:
            if word.lower() in line.lower():
               print word + "     " + line
```

Comment: `import re` becomes irrelevant, then :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean IGNORECASE? Try re.search(word2, line, re.IGNORECASE).